# send file/s in email with laravel and Mail function

Tags: php, laravel, email

I´m traying to send file or files with function \Mail in Laravel. And i´m a function to upload this file or files into a folder. My problem it´s i can´t to do that this file/s have send in one mail.

I have a `<input type="file" multiple/>` and with jquery i´m capturing his contain and it´s send to my controller where i´m doing a var_dump to show it. All contain it´s correct:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile)#262 (7) {
    ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
    string(11) "Captura.PNG"
    ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
    ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
    int(0)
    ["hashName":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
    string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpA1D4.tmp"
    ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
    string(11) "phpA1D4.tmp"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile)#266 (7) {
    ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
    string(12) "Captura3.PNG"
    ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
    ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
    int(0)
    ["hashName":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
    string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpA1D5.tmp"
    ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
    string(11) "phpA1D5.tmp"
  }
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "Captura.PNG"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "Captura3.PNG"
}
```

But i can´t attach into email:

```
\Mail::send('email', $datos, function($msj) use($subject, $emailUnico, $adjunto){

                    $msj->from("administrador@incidencias.integra.com","Incidencias");
                    $msj->subject($subject);
                    $msj->to($emailUnico);

                    for( $i=0; $i<count($adjunto); $i++ ){
                        $msj->attach($adjunto[$i], [
                            'as' => $adjunto[$i], // If you want you can chnage original name to custom name      
                            'mime' => 'application/pdf'
                        ]);
                    }
```

this is my function where i´m sending my email and attach mys file/s.

with this, i´m create a array with names and files from request:

```
for( $i=0; $i<count($request->file('adjunto')); $i++ ){
       $adjunto[] = $request->file('adjunto')[$i];
       $nombreAdjunto[] = $request->file('adjunto')[$i]->getClientOriginalName();
 }


 echo var_dump($adjunto);
 echo var_dump($nombreAdjunto);

 exit();
```

how i said before, all content it´s correct before i exposed my web browser console result.

i apreciatte all help with this problem.

Comment: Both of your uploaded files are of mimetype `image/png`, according to the debug output. So what is `'mime' => 'application/pdf'` then …?

Comment: @CBroe i´m traying with PDF files also i have this error 500: Unable to open file for reading [C:\xampp\tmp\php41A8.tmp]

Comment: Where is the part where you are moving the uploaded files to a permanent location? Why are you not using these “new” file paths afterwards, when trying to attach them to your mail?

Comment: Are you sure that your files size is not exceed your PHP configuration ? You should check these lines:upload_max_filesize = 2M
post_max_size = 2M

Comment: @CBroe how i could to do this ??? because i´m upload my files in folder "subidas" and i need get it from this folder but i don´t know as

Comment: @TrầnQuangSơn yes my php configuration it´s ok

Comment: @CBroe always if ichange my code and i add public_path()."/subidas"...  this is the error production.ERROR: Unable to open file for reading [C:\xampp\htdocs\incidencias\public/subidas/C:\xampp\tmp\php5990.tmp]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solve my problem. Only i would have to do this:

```
\Mail::send('email', $datos, function($msj) use($subject, $emailUnico, $adjunto){

                    $msj->from("administrador@incidencias.integra.com","Incidencias");
                    $msj->subject($subject);
                    $msj->to($emailUnico);

                    for( $i=0; $i<count($adjunto); $i++ ){
                        $msj->attach(public_path()."/subidas/".$adjunto[$i]->getClientOriginalName(), [
                            'as' => $adjunto[$i]->getClientOriginalName(), // If you want you can chnage original name to custom name      
                            'mime' => 'application/pdf'
                        ]);
                    }
                

                });
```

add public_folder and in "as" add originalName

Answer (score 0):

```
**Install the package**

Package : `"niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf": "^2.0"`

**Use the namespace**

use PDF;
use Mail;



public function pdfEmailSend(Request $request, $collectionOrArray)
        {
            $mailData = [
                'email' => $request->email,
            ];
    
            $filename = time() . "_demo_download.pdf";
            $pdfFilePath = public_path() . "/tempDir/" . $filename;
            $pdf = PDF::loadView('demo_pdf', compact('collectionOrArray'))->save($pdfFilePath);
    
            $data = array(
                'name' => "Mail Heading.",
            );
    
            Mail::send('mail_heading_blade_file', $data, function ($message) use ($pdfFilePath, $mailData) {
                $message->to($mailData['email'])->subject('Email Subject');
                $message->attach($pdfFilePath);
                $message->from('from@mail.com', 'Demo Company');
            });
    
            if (file_exists($pdfFilePath)) {
                unlink($pdfFilePath);
            }
    
            if (count(Mail::failures()) > 0) {
                return redirect()->route('redirect_route')->with('errorMsg', 'Something Error Found !, Please try again.');
            } else {
                return redirect()->route('redirect_route')->with('successMsg', 'Mail Has Been Sent Successfully');
            }
        }
```